# Placing label along line problems

Tags: qgis, labeling, line

I would like to get the map rotation python code (it varies depending on the atlas rotation). My goal is to create a label along a line offset in a perpendicular direction. I am using the code: , but map rotation does not work with respect to the map atlas.

[efect on work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhGsm.png)

[image: effect on print zone]

[image: code]

[image: my effect in work place]

Comment: Which code are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it is just on photo. Code: array(10*cos(radians(360-"azymut"- @map_rotation)),-10*sin(radians(360-"azymut"- @map_rotation))). Azymuth is rotation of line.